# How to count amount of decimals in float in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I need to check the amount of decimals in float number for my task, for validating the input, how can I do that?

Comment: Floating-point variables don't have decimal places. They have binary places.

Comment: Dealing with numbers for which the number of decimals matters, and is bounded, seems like an ideal case for fixed point scaled integers. For example, if you expect up to 3 decimal places, work in an integer number of thousandths.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot hope to do this because a float is held in binary floating point and not decimal. So, for instance, 0.1 cannot be represented exactly in a binary floating point variable. And if you cannot represent the number exactly, then you cannot reason about its representation.

If you wish to represent a number as decimal, then you must use a decimal representation rather than a binary representation.

Required reading on this topic: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About
Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Actually, if the value stored in a binary floating point of type `F` has less than `std::numeric_limits<F>::digits10` digits the exact decimal value can be restored, e.g., using Steele&White's Dragon4. You'd just count the digits there. Admittedly, you'd loose the count of trailing zeros as binary floating points are normalized.

Comment: @DietmarKühl You can define round trip conversions.  It's not clear that that's what is being asked, however.  To me, the question actually shows an ignorance of floating point representations, and David's answer addresses this best (IMHO).  All that's missing is a reference to "Everything you wanted to know about floating point".

Comment: @James It's there now!

Comment: @DietmarKühl: No, you cannot recover the original value with just the floating-point value. You must also have the information that the original value was expressible as a decimal numeral with a certain limit on the number of its digits. Otherwise, there are infinitely many possible original values that it is impossible to choose between. Since this question seeks to validate user input, the information about how many digits there were is not present; that is in fact the information being sought.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: It seems clear that the input is decimal. If the number of original digits didn't exceed `std::numeric_limits<F>::digits10` the number of original decimal digits (except for trailing zeros) can be recovered! There is no need to know how many decimal digits there were in the original. That's the central theorem of Steele&White's ["How to print floating-point numbers accurately"](http://http://kurtstephens.com/files/p372-steele.pdf); see section 8.

Comment: @DietmarKühl If the objective is to validate the number of decimal digits in the input, how can one know in advance that the number of decimal digits was less than a particular value?

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Your comment contains exactly the premise I stated is required: You must have the information that the number of input digits did not exceed a certain value. That premise does not exist in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Validating the input should be done when you have the input. You should examine the input text and decide whether it is acceptable or not.

When a decimal numeral is converted to binary floating-point, the value is often rounded, because binary floating-point cannot exact represent most decimal values. Thus, when you examine a `float` that is a result of this conversion, you no longer have the original input, so you cannot perform exact operations on the original input.

Comment: +1 Any error report should include the **exact** text being rejected, including leading and trailing zeros that are inevitably lost on conversion.

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation I once found, like user2699298's answer but should have a couple of quirks fixed. I didnt test all possible combinations, but it seems to do the job fine for the tests shown below. I suggest you decide for yourself if that is sufficient..

```
#include <cmath>
template< class T >
unsigned NumberOfDecimalPlaces( const T& num, const unsigned maxNumberOfDecimalPlacesReturned, const T& threshold = 1e-12 )
{
  static_assert( std::is_floating_point< T >::value,
   "NumberOfDecimalPlaces if for floating point numbers only" );

  T number = std::abs( num );
  unsigned numDecimalPlaces = 0;
  while( ( number - std::floor( number ) ) > threshold &&
         ( std::ceil( number ) - number ) > threshold )
  {
    if( ++numDecimalPlaces >= maxNumberOfDecimalPlacesReturned )
      break;
    number *= 10.0;
  }
  return numDecimalPlaces;
}
```

some tests:

```
TEST( NumberOfDecimalPlaces_Is_0_For_0 )
{
  CHECK_EQUAL( 0u, NumberOfDecimalPlaces( 0.0, 20 ) );
}

TEST( NumberOfDecimalPlaces_Yields_Max )
{
  CHECK_EQUAL( 5u, NumberOfDecimalPlaces( 0.11121212, 5 ) );
  CHECK_EQUAL( 5u, NumberOfDecimalPlaces( 0.00000001, 5 ) );
}

TEST( NumberOfDecimalPlaces_WorksOk_ForPrettyNormalNumbers )
{
  CHECK_EQUAL( 1u, NumberOfDecimalPlaces( 0.1, 20 ) );
  CHECK_EQUAL( 1u, NumberOfDecimalPlaces( 0.8, 20 ) );
  CHECK_EQUAL( 8u, NumberOfDecimalPlaces( 0.11121212, 20 ) );
  CHECK_EQUAL( 8u, NumberOfDecimalPlaces( 0.00000001, 20 ) );
  CHECK_EQUAL( 7u, NumberOfDecimalPlaces( 0.0000001, 20 ) );

  //this is represented as 0.0000000109999999
  CHECK_EQUAL( 9u, NumberOfDecimalPlaces( 0.000000011, 20 ) );
}
```

Comment: should return maxNumberOfDecimalPlacesReturned

Comment: Is it possible to re-write it to a simple functions, because I don't know templates yet?

Comment: just remove the line `template< class T >` and replace all `T` with `double` or `float`. But this is exactly what the compiler does under the hood, so now you know that you might as well just use the template version :P - that being said, the other answers are all pretty much valid: are you *sure* you want to count decimals like this?

Comment: I get following errors: `'is_floating_point' is not a member of 'std'`, `expected primary-expression before 'float'` on this line `' static_assert( std::is_floating_point<float>::value,` and third error `'static_assert' was not declared in this scope`. How can I fix them? And if possible without usage of C++11.

Comment: is_floating_point/static_assert are C++11.. However it's just a simple compiletime check so just remove the line and you'll be fine

Answer (score 1):

The question usually is "How many digits (precision) do I need?".

Let us take two fractions, 1/10 and 22/7.

With 1/10, which evaluates to 0.1, is there really only one digit after the decimal point or is 0.1000 still valid.  Search the web for "Significant digits".

With the fraction 22/7, how many digits are there after the decimal point?
With irrational numbers, there may be a sequence that repeats or not.  For example, 1/3, repeats after the first decimal.  The value for PI however, doesn't repeat?

Or are you asking for the number of digits before the decimal point?
This may be answered using `log` functions.
  `number of digits before decimal point = log(number) / log(10);`

Answer (score 0):

```
int decimals_float (float number){
    float num = number;       // local variable to hold the number
    int count = 0;            // variable to count the decimals
    num = abs(num);           // take the absolute value of the number (no negatives)
    num = num - (int)num;     // take off the digit and leave only decimals in the number
    while(num >= 0.1){        // checking until >= 0.1, because if we use != or >= 0 it might not work
        num *= 10;            // multiply the number by 10, to remove one decimal
        count++;              // add one to the decimals
        num -= (int)num;      // take off the digit and leave only decimals in the number
    }
    return count;             // return amount of decimals
}
```

Comment: decimals_float(0.09) == 0

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Actually, my bad. I shouldn't have done `>= 0.1`, instead I should have done `>= 0.0000001` I think.

Comment: Warning: compiles without warnings but behaves completely incorrectly if you only include `<stdlib.h>` for a declaration for `abs`. Oops on my part. :)

Comment: Actually, nothing can solve this problem. What is special about 0.0000001.

Comment: Hm. Agreed with David Heffernan, even after fixing that locally, so that the correct overload of `abs` is used, it just plain doesn't work, and doesn't seem fixable.

Comment: @user3182683 So, you make that change, and now `decimals_float(0.099) == 21`. You need to understand about representability.